# angular js foreach check duplicate values before push into the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using below array for my foreach function

```
  $scope.categoryList =  [
    {
        "id": 44,
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-11-15 17:11:17",
        "name": "FIXED ",
        "description": "FIXED",
        "$$hashKey": "object:108"
    },
    {
        "id": 44,
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-11-15 17:09:32",
        "name": "SAV",
        "description": "SAV",
        "$$hashKey": "object:109"
    },
    {
        "id": 76,
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-08-17 14:19:14",
        "name": "TEST CAT",
        "description": "TEST CAT",
        "$$hashKey": "object:110"
    },
    {
        "id": 77,
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-08-17 14:19:14",
        "name": "TEST CAT",
        "description": "TEST CAT",
        "$$hashKey": "object:110"
    } 
 
]
```

I need to get ids from the above array. I need to remove duplicate values before the push method.

this is my code

```
   angular.forEach($scope.categoryList, function (object) {
                    $scope.myNewarray.push(object.id);
                });
```

my new array data should be like as below

```
$scope.myNewarray = [44,76,77]
```

I need to get unique ids only for the my new array.

Comment: If you are open to using external libraries, you might consider using the lodash uniquBy function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the unique value from the array

```
$scope.categoryList = [
  {
    id: 44,
    creationTimestamp: "2019-11-15 17:11:17",
    name: "FIXED ",
    description: "FIXED",
    $$hashKey: "object:108",
  },
  {
    id: 44,
    creationTimestamp: "2019-11-15 17:09:32",
    name: "SAV",
    description: "SAV",
    $$hashKey: "object:109",
  },
  {
    id: 76,
    creationTimestamp: "2021-08-17 14:19:14",
    name: "TEST CAT",
    description: "TEST CAT",
    $$hashKey: "object:110",
  },
  {
    id: 77,
    creationTimestamp: "2021-08-17 14:19:14",
    name: "TEST CAT",
    description: "TEST CAT",
    $$hashKey: "object:110",
  },
];

$scope.myNewarray = [...new Set($scope.categoryList.map((o) => o.id))];
```